# IIS URLRewrite dynamic rule

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module, arr

I am trying to write an IIS URLRewrite rule that could be used dynamically using server variables instead of hard-coding. I tried several variables but can't seem to get to work.

I have a rule http://domain.com/myweb/appname/ that rewrites to http://myweb.com/appname/ which is hard-coded currently. I am hoping to have myweb and appname to be dynamic so I don't have to create a separate rule for each website and apps that I rewrite. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<rule name="Inbound URL">
   <match url="appname/(.*)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://myweb.com/appname/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
   <serverVariables>
     <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
   </serverVariables>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but still.. If you're after rewriting http://domain.com/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz?qqqq to http://xxxx.com/yyyy/zzzz?qqqq then it should be something like this:

```
<rule name="Inbound URL">
   <match url="^([\da-z\.-]+)/([\/\w \.-]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{R:1}.com/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Note that ([\da-z.-]+) is meant to match only valid domain name characters. Path expression ([/\w .-]+) doesn't describe all allowed symbols, but you can always tweak it as you need.